# MySQL error while importing database

Tags: php, mysql

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'TYPE=MyISAM' at line 8""

```
#
# Table structure for table 'members'
#

CREATE TABLE `members` (
`member_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
`firstname` varchar(100) default NULL,
`lastname` varchar(100) default NULL,
`login` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
`passwd` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
PRIMARY KEY  (`member_id`)
) TYPE=MyISAM;



#
# Dumping data for table 'members'
#

INSERT INTO `members` (`member_id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `login`, `passwd`)                   VALUES("1", "Jatinder", "Thind", "phpsense", "ba018360fc26e0cc2e929b8e071f052d");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [1064 error in CREATE TABLE ... TYPE=MYISAM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428755/1064-error-in-create-table-type-myisam)

Answer (score 2):

Try using 'ENGINE' instead of 'TYPE' :

```
CREATE TABLE `members` (
 `member_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `firstname` varchar(100) default NULL,
 `lastname` varchar(100) default NULL,
 `login` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
 `passwd` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`member_id`)
 ) ENGINE=MYISAM;
```

For more information check the [MySql Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html).

As far as I know 'TYPE' is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

The `TYPE` option was deprecated in MySQL 4 and removed in MySQL 5.5, so you probably want:

```
 CREATE TABLE `members` (
     `member_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
     `firstname` varchar(100) default NULL,
     `lastname` varchar(100) default NULL,
     `login` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
     `passwd` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
      PRIMARY KEY  (`member_id`)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

See the [MySQL CREATE TABLE documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.5-en/create-table.html) for details.